# Processing select form value with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a very simple form:

```
  <form id="signup">
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" name="tn" placeholder="tn" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="em" placeholder="em" id="em" required>                                   
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is process by a small js file:

```
$(function() {

    var form = $('#signup');
    var formMessages = $('#form');

    $(form).submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $('#thanks').hide();
        var formData = {
            'trackingnumber'    : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=courier]').val(),
            'courier'           : $('input[name=em]').val(),
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'signup.php', 
            data        : formData, 
            dataType    : 'json'
        }) 
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
        });

    });

});
```

I am looking to change the input for 'em' to an drop down box using select.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="em" placeholder="em" id="em" required>
         <select name="em">
             <option value="1">Saab</option>
             <option value="2">Rover</option>
             <option value="3">Daewoo</option>
             <option value="4">Ford</option>
             <option value="5">Peugeot</option>
         </select>
</div>
```

How do I access the value in the JS file?

I tried changing the line from:

```
'courier'           : $('input[name=em]').val(),
```

to

```
'courier'           : $('select[name=em]').val(),
```

but it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: 'courier'           : $('input[name=em]').val(),   looks like theres an extra comma at the end there

Comment: Your form isn't working is what you mean, to be clear? The given selector should work, but you should probably remove the input with [em=name]. The problem I see is that form selector you're using to attach submit callback, `$('#form')`, doesn't exist in the provided markup.

Comment: You could try `$('#em selected: Selected').val();`

Comment: ^ shouldn't need to; also wat? The select el the OP's trying to get the value of doesn't have [id=em], only [name=em].

Comment: And as @todd said, it is not $('#form') it may be $('form') without #

Comment: Minor tip regarding `var form = $('#signup')…$(form)`; the first assignment points to a jQuery object already, so `$(form)` and `form` are identical. Re-wrapping has the disadvantage of being unnecessary work.

Comment: The form works perfectly fine without the select dropdown. When I add it, the select value doesn't appear to be processed/received by the JS and therefore is not sent to the PHP script to be process. In formData courier is set to NULL.

Comment: @Todd it has an [id=em]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Description

To make this code runnable I changed it from a `form` to a `div`, I also had to change `.submit` to `.on('click',` not huge changes.

A `select` in html doesn't need to be wrapped with an input, because it was wrapped (and not encapsulated `<input><select></select></input>` it didn't work as you were expecting.  The below html should work fine.

### Changes

**JS**

```
'courier': $('select[name=em]').val(),
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="em" required>
     <option value="1">Saab</option>
     <option value="2">Rover</option>
     <option value="3">Daewoo</option>
     <option value="4">Ford</option>
     <option value="5">Peugeot</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

### Live Example

```js
$(function() {

  var form = $('#signup');
  var formMessages = $('#form');

  $('#signup .btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#thanks').hide();
    var formData = {
      'trackingnumber': $('input[name=email]').val(),
      'email': $('input[name=courier]').val(),
      'courier': $('select[name=em]').val(),
    };

    console.log(formData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="signup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="tn" placeholder="tn" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select name="em" required>
             <option value="1">Saab</option>
             <option value="2">Rover</option>
             <option value="3">Daewoo</option>
             <option value="4">Ford</option>
             <option value="5">Peugeot</option>
         </select>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this -

```
<div class="form-group">
     <!--<input type="text" name="em" placeholder="em" id="em" required>-->
         <select name="em" id="em">
             <option value="1">Saab</option>
             <option value="2">Rover</option>
             <option value="3">Daewoo</option>
             <option value="4">Ford</option>
             <option value="5">Peugeot</option>
         </select>
</div>

$('#em option:selected').val();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It turns out it was an extra comma spotted by samson!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$selectBlock = $('#YourSelectTagHere');
selectedOption = $selectBlock.options[$selectBlock.selectedIndex].val();
```